# Why is substring searching using 'in' operator, faster than using KMP algorithm?

Tags: python, string, algorithm

I have come across the KMP algorithm for substring searching and implemented it in python. Later, I found that the `in` operator can also be used for this problem and I decided to compare their performances. To my surprise, `in` was much faster than the KMP algorithm and I decided to take a closer look at `in`.

I found that `in` implements `__contains__` method in a string which is for containment check as suggested in [Datamodel doc](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html). But couldn't get further as to why it's faster.

Here's my implementation of KMP algorithm:

```
def lps(pattern):
    start_ind = 0
    lps_list = [0]
    for j in pattern[1:]:
        if(j == pattern[start_ind]):
            lps_list.append(start_ind)
            start_ind += 1
        else:
            start_ind = 0
            lps_list.append(start_ind)
    return lps_list
```

```
def kmp(search, pattern):
    lps_list = lps(pattern)
    pat_ind = 0
    for j in search:
        if(pat_ind == len(pattern)):
            return True
        if(j == pattern[pat_ind]):
            pat_ind += 1
            continue
        while(j != pattern[pat_ind] and pat_ind != 0):
            pat_ind = lps_list[pat_ind - 1]
        if(pat_ind == 0 and j == pattern[pat_ind]):
                pat_ind += 1
    else:
        if(pat_ind == len(pattern)):
            return True
        return False
```

The Driver block:

```
start = timeit.default_timer()
print('Found!!') if(kmp(search, pattern)) else print('Nope')
print(f'KMP algorithm: {(timeit.default_timer() - start):0.8e}')

start = timeit.default_timer()
print('Found!!') if(pattern in search) else print('Nope')
print(f'in operator: {(timeit.default_timer() - start):0.8e}')
```

Test case and result:

```
search = ''.join(['a' for _ in range(10000)] + ['b'])
pattern = ''.join(['a' for _ in range(1000)] + ['b'])
```

```
Found!!
KMP algorithm: 4.42536000e-03
Found!!
in operator: 3.72060003e-05
```

I expected the KMP algorithm to be not as slow as the results suggest since it is a decent substring searching algorithm. I couldn't understand if it is, me missing something with my test cases or due to Python's way of storing strings.

Comment: Here is some historic context on the builtin: http://effbot.org/zone/stringlib.htm

Comment: Also bear in mind that the builtin is written in C whereas you KMP is in pure Python (incurring a large multiplicative performance penalty since it's interpreted).

Comment: What algorithm do you think Python uses?  See [the source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/stringlib/fastsearch.h).  Here are [notes](http://effbot.org/zone/stringlib.htm) from the implementer: "This rules out most standard algorithms (**Knuth-Morris-Pratt** is not sublinear, Boyer-Moore needs tables that depend on both the alphabet size and the pattern size, most Boyer-Moore variants need tables that depend on the pattern size, etc.).

After some tweaking, I came up with a simplication of Boyer-Moore, incorporating ideas from Horspool and Sunday."

Comment: If you want to see worst-case behavior from Python's `str.__contains__`, try searching for `'a'*1000+'ba'`. Your test would put the simplest naive string searches into worst-case performance, but `str.__contains__` needs a slightly harder case.

Comment: @NPE, haven't thought of that. It makes sense.

Comment: @user2357112, I have tried it and it works!! KMP is faster for that test case. I will update the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in the comments to the question, the internal string searching algorithm is faster in the best cases but also slower in the worst cases than KMP algorithm. The worst cases being rarer. Here's some [background](http://effbot.org/zone/stringlib.htm), and the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/stringlib/fastsearch.h) of its implementation. And the fact that it's implemented in C makes it faster.
Below is a worst case for `str.__contains__` and result:

```
search = 'a' * 10000000 + 'ba'
pattern = 'a' * 10000 + 'ba'
```

```
Found!!
KMP algorithm: 3.29188600e+00
Found!!
in operator: 3.85637655e+01
```